# How do I force a job to be a success in my GitHub Actions even if the steps fail?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow, clang-format

I'm trying to make it such that when someone pushes to my repo, the code-formatter is run on files changed in the push. To do so, I use git diff in my GitHub Workflow .yml file.

It looks like this (removed irrelevant commands such as installing clang-format for cleanliness):

```yaml
  clang-format:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2  # Fetch all history for accurate results
  
      // ... Install clang-format here
      
      - name: Run clang-format on changed files
        run: |
          OLD_COMMIT=${{ github.event.before }}
          NEW_COMMIT=${{ github.sha }}
          CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only $OLD_COMMIT $NEW_COMMIT)
          if [ -n "$CHANGED_FILES" ]; then
            for file in $CHANGED_FILES; do
              if [[ $file == *.cpp || $file == *.h ]]; then
                  clang-format -i -style=file "$file"
              fi
            done
          else
            echo "No changed .h or .cpp files found."
          fi || true  # Ignore errors if there are no changed files
       
      // ... Push changes here
```

This works great if there are multiple commits in the open PR, but if there's only one, I get the error `"bad object: <OLD_COMMIT_HASH>"`

I'd like to have it such that if the push only has one commit, it either can successfully handle this, or just always succeed even in spite of a "bad object" error since it works perfectly fine in other cases.

I've tried a few things, such as
`COMMIT_COUNT=$(git rev-list --count ${{ github.event.before }}..${{ github.sha }})`
to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].continue-on-error`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error).

Comment: I would recommend checking the value of `github.event.before` and handling when that's empty/null or whatever it is when only one commit instead of continue on error. There might be other errors that you don't want to continue from.

Comment: Unfortunately continue on error did not work. It kept going, but gave me a fail 'X'

Comment: The github actions dashboard has it as a success, but the PR will still say I failed a test